# How to count total number of rows of table in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, rowcount

How to count the total number of rows of table and pass it to the variable? For example, I have product table and there are 10 products in it. I want to count all the rows and get the result 10 and pass it to the variable $rowcount. How can I do it?

Answer (score 12):

use [find('count')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-count)

For example:

```
$total = $this->Article->find('count');
```

If you want to use a condition in your query, then pass the conditions array, here is a sample code:

```
$pending = $this->Article->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Article.status' => 'pending')));
```

Comment: what about with conditions?

Answer (score 7):

you also try this with condition

```
$rowcount = $this->Product->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Product.fieldName' => 'value')
```

Answer (score 4):

u can do it with find('count') method

```
$this->set('rowcount',$this->Product->find('count'));
```

or simply use count() function if had already the products in a variable $products to avoid another Mysql query

```
$this->set('rowcount',count($products));
```

Answer (score 1):

By Using this you can count data with passing conditions in where

```
    $assignment = TableRegistry::get('Assignment');
    $query = $assignment->find();
    $query->select(['count' => $query->func()->count('id')]);
    $query->where(['Assignment.user_id'=>$user_id]);
    $assignment = $query->toArray();
    $assignment_count = $assignment[0]->count;
    return  $assignment_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3.x you can query like this:

```
$count = $this->Students->find()->count();
```

Or

```
TableRegistry::get('Students')->find()->count();
```

Here student is example model. Replace with your model name. 
Thanks.